# Question about the floating point values in xcode

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c, xcode

I have two floating point numbers. If I add that 2 numbers means. It will displaying the answer as 4.50000 (I used just %f). If I used (2.%f) means the answer is just 4.
  I want the answer as 4.5. What do I have to modify in this?

Comment: could you provide your source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the format string `%2.1f`:

```
$ printf "%2.1f\n" 4.5
4.5
```

The `.1` says "one character after the radix".

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to use `"%2.1f"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one

NSLog(@"%.1f",floatVariable);